# $routeChangeStart getting called multiple times in IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-ng-route

We are supporting IE8 browser for our application. Recently we are upgraded angular version from 1.0.8 to 1.2.16

application with newer version works in all browsers however we seen the issue with ngRoute in IE8.

It broadcasts the "$routeChangeStart" multiple times.

$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", (event: ng.IAngularEvent, next, current) => {

});

To identify i have added console.log inside above code it getting called twice in IE8 only.

In angular version 1.0.8 same code snippet gives one time console.log comments in browser console.

Is there any issue with ngRoute (angular version 1.2.16) for IE8 ??

Comment: I have the same exact problem with the same version of angular, leadin in: "Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Comment: Could you post the source code here? If possible, you could change to ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) which has the support for older browser.

Answer (score 2):

Can you search your project so you don't have any `$route.reload()` in any file? This would make the application call the $routeChangeStart 2 times.

Comment: Thanks. You saved me some time investigating ;)